# How to make a flutter app react to network changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this method, in one of my classes, that registers a listener to watch for connectivity changes:

```
  static _watchNetworkChanges() {
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((status){
      if (status == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        // Do something...
      }
    });
  }
```

But apparently, the closure passed to the `listen` method is never called, no matter what I try (enable/disable wi-fi, mobile network, etc.)

The `Connectivity` class is part of this lib:
http://47.75.70.92/documentation/connectivity/0.4.1/

Does anyone know how to make this work?

**EDIT:**
I found out that this listener works if it is written inside an `initState()` method of a `StatefulWidget`. But that doesn't help me, because I'm writing a library and therefore I will have no widgets inside it.

Comment: It sounds like `_watchNetworkChanges()` is never called - Dart does not invoke `static` methods when a library is imported, so you'll need to call it explicitly from somewhere.

Comment: Hey @NateBosch, thanks for answering. I know that, this method is actually called inside my library. I tested it in the main.dart file inside its example package. So, `_watchNetworkChanges` is being called, but the closure passed to the `listen` method is not.

Comment: Either `_watchNetworkChanges()` isn't being called, or there is a bug in `package:connectivity` and the Stream isn't emitting any events. I don't see any issue with the `.listen()` call here.